# How to disable source field and use store with Nest?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to disable source as it is done [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) initially. I am not sure how to achieve similar like in the sample

```
PUT tweets
{
  "mappings": {
    "tweet": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried below but when I enter http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/; I can see  that all the properties are stored. I expect to store and index only id and name properties.

```
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
 var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "mydatabase");              
 var client = new ElasticClient(settings);  
 var createIndexResult = client.CreateIndex("mydatabase");  
  var mapResult = client.Map<Product>(c => c.MapFromAttributes().SourceField(s=>s.Enabled(false)).IgnoreConflicts().Type("product").Indices("mydatabase"));


 client.Index(sampleproduct);



  [ElasticType(Name ="product", IdProperty = "ProductId" )]
  [Table("Product")]
    public partial class Product
    {      

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "id",Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = true)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Store = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.No, Store = false)]
    public int? ProductTypeId { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.No, Store = false)]
    public int? ManufacturerId { get; set; }

    }
```

EDIT: without adding any documents after creating index, index metadata looks like in the image. i dont see any source enabled false. [image]

EDIT2: after changing creating index first then mapping. Name field is displaying store=true as in the image but there is no value stored. I debugged and i am surely passing value where i index the sampleproduct

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the mapping first and then index the document. Only then will you see the get the expected mapping. By indexing first without the mapping, a mapping gets dynamically created with default options (source being enabled).

Comment: I have just tried but it didnt really help. I can still see the store=no properties. I updated my question with how I tried. do you mean like above?

Comment: Nope you're still doing it wrong. First create the index, then create the mapping and only after that index documents. In your updated question, you're creating the mapping before creating the index which is wrong.

Comment: BTW, you can add the mapping at the same time as creating the index. But @bittusarkar is right, create the index first (optionally specifying the mapping at the same time).

Comment: I just did that and it worked and I can see that source enabled is false but although store=true for name. I cant see name field is stored.  search also didnt work for name although i say that it is indexed. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @bittusarkar i added 2nd edit with screenshot and explanation above.

Comment: In your mapping you set `name` field to be stored and `_source` is disabled. In the result of a search request, besides some metadata fields, value of `_source` field is returned by default. Now that you have `_source` disabled, if you need to fetch the value of `name` field, you need to mention that in `"fields"` section of the search request, like `"fields": [ "name" ]`. Read more about using `fields` at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html.

Comment: @bittusarkar is that slowing the query? I mean using fields does any impact on performance?